# YouTube Data API Build Function doesn´t work

Tags: youtube-data-api

friends.

Yesterday I used the below python piece of code to retrieve some comments on youtube videos sucessfully:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery

DEVELOPER_KEY = "my_key"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
youtube
```

It seems that the build function is suddenly not working. I have even refreshed the API, but in Google Colab I keep receiving the following error message:

```
UnknownApiNameOrVersion                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-064a9ae417b9> in <module>()
     13 
     14 
---> 15 youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
     16 youtube
     17 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in build(serviceName, version, http, discoveryServiceUrl, developerKey, model, requestBuilder, credentials, cache_discovery, cache, client_options)
    241                 raise e
    242 
--> 243     raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion("name: %s  version: %s" % (serviceName, version))
    244 
    245 

UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: youtube  version: V3
```

If anyone could help. I´m using this type of authentication because I dont know to put the credentials file in google drive and open it in Colab. But it worked yesterday:

[Results for yesterday´s run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKZOg.png)

Thank you very much in advance. And sorry for anything, Im new in the community.

Regards

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue (we are on version 1.7.8, Python 3.6.8). It has now been raised here by others as well:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/882

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on the server side as discussed [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/882). Until the server problem is fixed, this solution may help (as suggested by [@busunkim96](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/882#issuecomment-618514530)):

First, download this json file: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest

Then:

```py
import json
from googleapiclient import discovery

# Path to the json file you downloaded:
path_json = '/path/to/file/rest'

with open(path_json) as f:
    service = json.load(f)

# Replace with your actual API key:
api_key = 'your API key'

yt = discovery.build_from_document(service,
                                   developerKey=api_key)

# Make a request to see whether this works:
request = yt.search().list(part='snippet',
                           channelId='UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw',
                           publishedAfter='2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z',
                           publishedBefore='2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z',
                           order='date',
                           type='video',
                           maxResults=50)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @ingo-marquardt : `Python 3.6 and google API 1.8.2 **on Colab**.`

Comment: Ok. I can reproduce the issue on colab, both with version `1.7.12` and `1.8.2`. Seems like a genuine bug, I'm not sure what to do, except to report the issue on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by putting making putting `static_discovery=False` into the build command

Examples:

**Previous Code**
`self.youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=creds`

**New Code**
`self.youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=creds, static_discovery=False)`

For some reason this issue only arised when I compiled my program using Github Actions