# Discord Music Bot Using YouTube Api

Tags: python, discord

I was trying to make a discord music bot with YouTube api I'm running in this poblem

```
UnknownApiNameOrVersion
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: youtube version: v3
```

I checked and they key is fine

Code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

import youtube_dl

import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from googleapiclient.errors import UnknownApiNameOrVersion

load_dotenv()

YOUTUBE_API_KEY = os.getenv("YOUTUBE_API_KEY")

class MusicPlayer(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):

        self.bot = bot

        self.voice_client = None

    @commands.Cog.listener()

    async def on_ready(self):

        print(f'Logged in as {self.bot.user.name}')

        print('------')

    @commands.command()

    async def join(self, ctx):

        # Check if the user is in a voice channel

        if ctx.author.voice is None:

            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")

            return

        

        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

        self.voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client

        # Connect to the voice channel

        if self.voice_client is None:

            self.voice_client = await channel.connect()

        else:

            await self.voice_client.move_to(channel)

    @commands.command()

    async def leave(self, ctx):

        # Disconnect from the voice channel

        if self.voice_client is not None:

            await self.voice_client.disconnect()

            self.voice_client = None

    @commands.command()

    async def play(self, ctx, *search_query):

        # Check if the bot is connected to a voice channel

        if self.voice_client is None or not self.voice_client.is_connected():

            await ctx.send("I am not connected to a voice channel.")

            return

        # Search for videos using YouTube Data API

        try:

            youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=YOUTUBE_API_KEY)

            query = ' '.join(search_query)

            request = youtube.search().list(part='snippet', q=query, type='video', maxResults=1)

            response = request.execute()

        except UnknownApiNameOrVersion as e:

            print(f"An error occurred while searching for videos: {e}")

            await ctx.send("The YouTube Data API is currently unavailable. Please try again later.")

            return

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"An error occurred while searching for videos: {e}")

            await ctx.send("An error occurred while searching for videos.")

            return

        # Check if any videos were found

        if len(response['items']) == 0:

            await ctx.send("No matching videos found.")

            return

        # Get the first video's ID

        video_id = response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']

        video_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'

        # Download the audio from YouTube URL using youtube_dl

        ydl_opts = {

            'format': 'bestaudio/best',

            'postprocessors': [{

                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',

                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',

                'preferredquality': '192',

            }],

            'outtmpl': 'song.mp3',

        }

        try:

            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:

                ydl.download([video_url])

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"An error occurred while downloading audio: {e}")

            await ctx.send("An error occurred while downloading audio.")

            return

        # Play the downloaded audio

        try:

            source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3')

            self.voice_client.play(source)

            await ctx.send("Now playing: " + response['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"An error occurred while playing the song: {e}")

            await ctx.send("An error occurred while playing the song.")

            return

def setup(bot):

    bot.add_cog(MusicPlayer(bot))
```

Comment: I found the following thing: [YouTube Data API Build Function doesn´t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365111/youtube-data-api-build-function-doesn´t-work). Does this help you?